# Как мне подключить виджеты Wordpress в файле footer.php?

Tags: wordpress

Я создаю дочернюю тему Wordpress. У меня есть 4 виджета в админке. Вопрос - Как мне подключить виджеты Wordpress в файле footer.php?

[image]

Comment: Создаешь сайдбар, кидаешь в него нужные виджеты и -  <?php get_sidebar("name") ?>